# How to properly change elements in a char [] in c

Tags: c

I am trying to create a function that takes in word from a file then normalizes it by deleting any punctuation or quotes. The problem I am having is that when I have a word that has `"` in the front or both the front and back like `"how"`, I get out put like this:

```
"howw"
 howwETX
"well
"wel
```

How do I stop this from happening?

```
char *normalize( int count, char entry[], char output[] ){

    count--;/* to allow for the zero index of an array*/

    if( entry[0] == '"' && entry[count] == '"' ){
        for(int i=1 , j=0;j < count - 1; i++,j++ ){
            output[j] = entry[i];
        }
        output[count + 1 ] = '\0';
        return output;

    }else if( entry[0] == '"' ){
        for(int i = 0 , j=0; j < count; i++, j++ ){
            output[j] = entry[i];
        }
        output[count++] = '\0';
        return output;

    } else if( entry[count] == '"' || ispunct( entry[count] ) ){
        for(int i=0 , j=0;i < count; i++,j++ ){
            output[j] = entry[i];
        }
        output[count] = '\0';
        return output;
    }

    return entry;
}/* ends normalize( int count, char entry[], char output[] )*/
```

Comment: Suggestion: simplify it. Don't try to look at more than one character at the time (like the start and end quotes). Instead, simply loop from beginning to end and accept or reject that single character. Not only you will get simpler and more readable code, but most likely you will solve the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not counting your indices correctly.

1. In the case where there are quotes front and back, the length of the output string is `count - 1`, after `count` has been updated, so you should set `output[count - 1] = '\0'` rather than `output[count + 1] = '\0'`. In fact, you may want to decalre `j` outside your loop and use `output[j]` since that will be the correct position in the string (in all three cases).
2. In the case where only the first character is a quote, you should skip the quote: `i = 1`, not `i = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's play debugger. Suppose your input is this:

```
entry == "a"
count == 3
```

We begin executing, and here's what happens:

```
count == 2

i == 1
j == 0
output[0] == 'a'
```

The loop exits and then:

```
output[3] == '\0'
```

So now `output` contains `aa"`, which is incorrect. The solution is to set `output[count-1]` to null when the loop exits, not `count + 1`.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following. At least it is correct and looks simpler.:)

```
char * normalize( char output[], const char entry[], size_t n )
{
    if ( n != 0 && entry[0] == '"' )
    {
        ++entry;
        --n;
    }

    if ( n != 0 && ispunct( entry[n-1] ) )
    {
        --n;
    }

    strncpy( output, entry, n );

    output[n] = '\0';

    return output;
}
```

Comment: "Loststudent1" is not going to learn much by getting a ready to use solution that even tries to optimise the task. I doubt the goal was to get the best algorithm. The other answers do teach something.

Comment: @cornuz it is my answer that teaches how to write code. All other answers are useless.

Comment: @cornuz I can learn more from code like this than from just a single line answer for example.